# Login to a Linux server from a Windows system using batch files

Tags: linux, batch-file, expect

i want to make one script which will automatic telnet the system . 
I have to access from my system(Windows Xp) to my server(Linux)

`spawn telnet <machine ip> 
expect "login:" 
send "<username>\n" 
expect "Password:" 
send "<password>\n"`

Is the above script is correct? 
1) If yes means, how can i access this script from my machine(WindowsXp)?
2) If yes means, i have to install expect package?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean! Are you trying to run a remote command via a batch file?

Comment: just i have to create a batch file. Once execute that file, it has to login my server(linux)

Answer (score 1):

use ssh instead of telnet and make use of public/private keys for authentication.
then use putty with command-line-arguments to login without a password.

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-ssh-keys-authentication-with-putty-and-linux-server-in-5-quick-steps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you. You can try these commands if you have [trusted remote hosts and users](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5174/hosts.equiv-4?l=en&a=view&q=hosts.equiv).

```
C:\> telnet -l user_name
```

and provide the password

OR you can do something like Unix

```
C:\> echo command | telnet -l user_name
```

Also for other details on telnet refer this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787407(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Its not exact one. But the link is given some input to me. 
Thanks

Comment: the commands are just examples. Please go through the details of telnet at the link to get your task done. If this is helpful for you please accept the answer.

Comment: Friend, I think so that you unable to understand my qtn. I need information from Dos commands than telnet. Once i login server(to samba or super or anyother linux server from windows OS) it will ask username password.
First to enter into server, we can give telnet or any other command. After that we have to give username & password to login that server.
In my batch files what commands i have to give.

I have given one of the example is telnet to access the server. now can you understand my problem?
Thanks in advance to your reply.